# Laravel: Retrieve data from DB and diplay in View

Tags: laravel, data-retrieval

I have a bug here in my code that show me a probleme while displaying data in the home page

Controller

```
class Annonce_indexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $annonce_residentiel = Annonce_residentiel::all();   
        return view('/' , compact('annonce_residentiel'));
    }
}
```

Route

```
  Route::get('/index','Annonce_indexController@index');
```

Blade View

```
{{  $annonce_residentiel->prix  }}
```

It says that $annonce_residentiel is undefined

**Edit:**
The problem is I have two routes to the same view:

```
Route::get('/','Admin\Annonce_indexController@index');
Route::get('/',array('as' =>'viewville','uses'=>'VilleController@index'));
```

**Solution**
Change the second route to post !

```
Route::get('/','Admin\Annonce_indexController@index');
Route::post('/',array('as' =>'viewville','uses'=>'VilleController@index'));
```

Comment: What happens if you `dd($annonce_residentiel)` inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

**$annonce_residentiel** is an object and not a variable so you cannot just call it and expect it to pop a value. For just demo purpose and to understand how it works try the following code in your view.

```
@foreach($annonce_residentiel as $data)
    {{ $data->prix }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's the same i only have 1 row in my table so no need for a foreach

Comment: even if you have one row still it will fetch it as an object

Comment: The problem is that the $annonce_residentiel variable doesn't pass to the view "it's not defined". It's not that I'm trying to convert an array to a string

Comment: Undefined variable: annonce_residentiel

Comment: can you try return View::make('/')->with(compact('annonce_residentiel'))

Comment: I tried I guess i locate the error it's that my controller is in a subfolder with the name of Admin so I have to run  composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
   class Annonce_indexController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $annonce_residentiel = Annonce_residentiel::first();   
            return view('/' , compact('annonce_residentiel'));
        }
    }
```

Blade View

```
{{  $annonce_residentiel->prix  }}
```

Comment: I found the problem it's that I have two route to the same view "index"
Route::get('/','Admin\Annonce_indexController@index');

Route::get('/',array('as' =>'viewville','uses'=>'VilleController@index'));